# ng-style [$parse:syntax] error in jade

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, pug

I've try to convert my code from html to jade and using express render it on server side.
here is my ng-repeat code snippet

```
ul.task-list
      li.published-list(ng-repeat='tsk in app.dataTask')
        div(ng-style='{"background-color":tsk.color}')
          input(type='checkbox', ng-model='tsk.status', ng-click='app.taskComplete(tsk)')
          span(ng-class='{"done":tsk.status}') {{tsk.contents}}
          span.align.glyphicon.glyphicon-align-justify
```

the strange thing is all the `tsk.status`,`tsk.status`,`tsk.contents` working fine and get value. but `tsk.color` cannot, it's working fine previously in html format, may I know how to write a correct ng-style in Jade?

the error I got from debug is

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.1/$parse/syntax?p0=Object&p1=is[object Object]nexpected%C%expecting%%5B%D%D&p2=9&p3=%Bobject%Object%D&p4=Object%D ...
```

Codepen sample:

Jade: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/khDIm

Html: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HpxBb

Comment: What's the value of `tsk.color`?

Comment: @Shomz it should be a String - '#21928' something like this

Comment: It could be related to quotes then. Could you try setting the whole style string to a variable (`tsk.style = "'background-color': '#123123'"`) and then doing: `ng-style="tsk.style"`?

Comment: @Shomz even `(tsk.style = "'background-color': '#123123'")` not working

Comment: @Shomz but change to html it works

Comment: Hmmm, and what's the rendered HTML output when you use jade? Also, could you create a live example of that somewhere?

Comment: @Shomz Just made a live one, please have a look http://codepen.io/anon/pen/khDIm

Comment: You forgot the curly braces: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cLEfh

Comment: @Shomz actually the problem is in Jade backgroundColor not background-color, you're right, thanks for help

Comment: Yup, that minus symbol can be tricky with templating engines. You're welcome.

Comment: @Shomz if got time, write a answer to this question and I can accept :)

Comment: Sure, although you could've written it as well. I don't care much about the points. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like using `backgroundColor` instead of `background-color` fixes the issue with Jade:

```
div(ng-style='{"backgroundColor":tsk.color}')
```